# Python timestamp difference in list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have FROM Timestamp and TO Timestamp in the list of tuples. I would like to get the timestamp difference in minutes present in the list of tuples.

For Ex:

```py
Timestamp_list = [
    (Timestamp("2021-09-13 07:00:00"), Timestamp("2021-09-13 10:00:00")),
    (Timestamp("2021-09-13 11:00:00"), Timestamp("2021-09-13 12:00:00")),
]
```

in the above list, the difference between `Timestamp('2021-09-13 07:00:00')` and `Timestamp('2021-09-13 10:00:00')` is `180` Minutes and the the difference between `Timestamp('2021-09-13 11:00:00')` and `Timestamp('2021-09-13 12:00:00')` is `60` Minutes. Altogether I have `240` Minutes. There could be N number of FROM and TO Timestamp in the list.

The expected result should be `240` minutes. Could you please help me in getting this done in Python. Thank you.

Comment: [mre]? What is wrong with what you coded? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = sum((b - a).seconds for a, b in Timestamp_list) // 60
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
240
```